# Joomla - A Few Queries in one function

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I try to use select then use insert or delete ... Insert And Delete works well but Select option doesn't work at all.I want to use select to display single rows and number of rows in table. Do i something wrong ?

```
 global $Itemid;
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $db2 = JFactory::getDBO();
    $mediaid = $_POST["addMediaId"];
    $delid = $_POST['delRow'];


        $query = ' SELECT id'
        . ' FROM #__mediamall_favourite_media'
        . ' WHERE mediaid = "'.$mediaid.'" AND userid = "'.$user->id.'"';

                    $db2->setQuery($query);
        $db2->query();

                $rows = $db2->getNumRows();
        $result = $db2->loadRowList();
        $del = $db2->loadObject();


    if(isset($_POST["submitCheck"]) && $_POST["submitCheck"] == "1") {             
        $query = " INSERT INTO `#__mediamall_favourite_media` (`id`, `userid`, `mediaid`) VALUES (NULL,'".$user->id."','".$mediaid."')";
    }    
    elseif(isset($_POST["submitCheck"]) && $_POST["submitCheck"] == "0") {     
        $query = " DELETE FROM `#__mediamall_favourite_media` WHERE `id` = '".$delid."' "; 
    }  

    if($query) {
        $db2->setQuery($query);
        $db2->query();

    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code and what would rather have happen?

Comment: i have a button which after click will add same data to sql after second click delete the same row from sql. I want to add select to check if in table are more than 5 row added by the same user . If yes user can not add no more data to this table

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues, some deal with security, some with code style (you're coding for Joomla, don't use php equivalents):

You must use `$db->quote()` on values coming from the user to prevent SQL injection attacks;

`$_POST` should not be used, use `JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('paramname')` or one of the more specific getInt etc.;

Now to the code:

$rows $result and $del are not used;

you don't need to `->query()` if you do ->loadObject and you could use a ->loadObjectList to gather all data you need.

The test on `$_POST["submitCheck"]` doesn't test the number of records; you should restructure with two queries; the first, `select count(*),max(id) from .... where userid = $user->id;` if the query returns a count>5, use max(id) to choose the row to delete;  But even easier, only insert if count<5 and avoid the delete altogether. Remember to let the user know otherwise it just seems like a bug.